# Magento checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, address

How to add Address verification block on payment step in magento2.

Please review below screen show link https://prnt.sc/irgs46

Comment: Sharak, please explain the question in briefly.Don't give a single screenshort

Comment: ok, If i fill wrong test address in shipping and go to the payment I see a block like attached screen shot https://prnt.sc/irgs46.
I want to known how this type of functionality works in magento2...please help me